# ResourceNotFound, The Resource Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/... under resource group '...' was not found

Tags: rest, azure, http, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I was running following azure rest api call through the console given in web. Though we set up every thing correctly and try to retrieve pipelines in the data factory attached to a resource group gives following error. Please help me out to if anyone know how to get rid of this error.

The Resource 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/avengersadf' under resource group 'ADFResourceGroup' was not found.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/guid/resourceGroups/ADFResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/avengersadf/pipelines/Dotnet%20Helloworld?api-version=2018-06-01
Authorization: Bearer xxx

Response Code: 404

cache-control: no-cache
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
expires: -1
pragma: no-cache
x-ms-correlation-request-id: aad8af0d-4fca-47df-ad48-2e627b402e87
x-ms-failure-cause: gateway
x-ms-request-id: aad8af0d-4fca-47df-ad48-2e627b402e87
x-ms-routing-request-id: SOUTHEASTASIA:20180903T184319Z:aad8af0d-4fca-47df-ad48-2e627b402e87
Body
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "/avengersadf' under resource group 'ADFResourceGroup' was not found."
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxML3.png)

Answer (score 2):

This means that there is no such a resource under this resource group. check spelling and\or subscription

ps. also, you should never post bearer tokens online, somebody could use that token to impersonate you, you really want to change password now